# "patch: **** Can't rename file" bash patch error

Tags: unix, patch

I am running these three commands.

```
cd "${folder1}"
diff -ruN "${folder1}" "${folder2}" > "${patchname}"
patch -f -s -d "${folder1}" --merge < "${patchname}"
```

When I run them it successfully changes the files in folder1 to the same as folder2. However when I run these commands I get the output.

`patch: **** Can't rename file ./update.patch.omMg8yG to update.patch : Operation not permitted`

Comment: `patch` is not part of bash, and can be used without bash installed at all.

Comment: that said, there are a few noteworthy items. Writing into a file in a directory you're incrementally diffing *at the same time as the write is ongoing* is not, generally speaking, a good idea; patch's behavior is not well-defined if files are being changed inline.

Comment: Is `update.patch` your value of `patchname`? Can you create a reproducer that's complete enough that someone else can run it (thus, responsible for creating and setting up contents in `folder1` and `folder2`, setting `patchname`, etc)?

Comment: Also, if you were running this on a platform that wasn't *really* a UNIX -- say, Cygwin -- then that other platform's file locking rules could apply such that a file that was being read couldn't be concurrently modified.

Comment: `update.patch` is the value of `patchname`. As for you second question I am not to sure what you are asking.

Comment: "Second question" being the one asking for a reproducer? See http://stackoverflow.com/help/mcve or http://sscce.org/. And the last question I asked (by implication) is what operating system exactly this is happening on.

Comment: (Directory ownership and permissions are also relevant for purposes of this error -- if you have write access to the files but not the directory they're in, that would explain it, but I'd like to exhaust other theories first).

Comment: @CharlesDuffy Thanks for your help again :) adding && is the fix so that it only patches after the write is completed as you suggested.

Comment: The default behavior of using `;` (or a newline following a syntactically complete command) is to wait for a command to finish before going onto the next, so that's actually not an expected fix.

Comment: so, what I meant by "diffing at the same time as the write" is that when you run `> "$patchname"`, that write to `patchname` is itself being done as `diff` runs and writes to its stodut.

Comment: ...if diff is considering the directory that the patch is in as input, then you're into a bunch of situations that it wasn't tested to be able to support. So the proper fix is just to have the patch *not be in either of the directories being diffed*.

Comment: @CharlesDuffy It was working before it just kept displaying that error that didn't seem to affect it in anyway.

Comment: The error means that it couldn't overwrite the patchfile itself (which is why I'm guessing you're on cygwin -- on a real UNIX you're allowed to rename over in-use files). But you don't **want** it to overwrite the patchfile itself, do you? So it did have an effect, it's just an effect you probably wanted. :)

Comment: ...but still, if your patchfile was in a more appropriate location, you wouldn't be relying on undocumented, platform-specific behavior to get that behavior that you want.

Comment: @CharlesDuffy Pretty much. I just wanted rid of the error since I wasn't causing harm.

Comment: (Some NFS implementations also don't like unlinked in-use files, so the cygwin guess isn't the only way to get there).

Comment: @CharlesDuffy I tried to put it somewhere else and it was complaining about absolute directories for path and not being able to find the file despite being in the correct folder.

Comment: Part of the point I'm trying to make is that it's only luck that's causing it not to cause harm: If you ran the same code in some other places, it *could* corrupt your patchfile. So you shouldn't rely on that behavior, and instead should fix it.

Comment: Absolute paths are perfectly legal for redirections, such as the only uses of the patchfile variable you're showing here (`> "$patchfile"` and `< "$patchfile"`). If you have a scenario where they can't be used, you haven't shown it yet.

Comment: @CharlesDuffy Don't worry I am. Wanted to understand what was the cause of that error and how to fix it so if I come across it again I can deal with it.

Answer (score 0):

The problem is here:

```
cd "${folder1}"
diff -ruN "${folder1}" "${folder2}" > "${patchname}"
```

You're *inside* `folder1`, and trying to create a patch that's also inside `folder1` (which we know because your log file is calling the file `./update.patch.omMg8yG`, explicitly referring to the current directory), which *contains a set of differences between `folder1` and `folder2`*, while those differences also include the contents of the output file itself -- the output file being generated *over the course of the `diff` operation*, and read over the course of `patch` operation.

---

Consequently, `patch` is **trying to change the patch file it's reading from**. It's failing, hence the error, but you shouldn't be having it make the attempt -- particularly since on most UNIXlike operating systems, this attempt wouldn't fail (I'm assuming you're on Cygwin, or on a remote filesystem mount that doesn't support open unlinked files).

Modify your `patchfile` variable to point to a location in a different directory, neither `folder1` or `folder2`.